# Create Task Report from Mylyn?

Tags: android-activity, report, mylyn

is there a way to create a task/activity report (say a weekly report) off tasks managed with Mylyn? I've been using Rachota TimeTracker which allows me to create reports (in html format)

http://rachota.sourceforge.net/en/demo.html

I've just started using mylyn (our company uses Embarcadero JBuilder which is is based on Eclipse), but I don't see anywhere in the Eclipse or Embarcadero docs about reporting capabilities.

Is it possible? Is it possible to query activities worked on a prior week and report statistics out of it (management like reports, you know;) I'm sure it is, but I haven't been able to google it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in luck, [Tasktop Pro](http://tasktop.com/support/download/) (the supported version of Mylyn) has reporting.  It allows you to:

- View all task activity times for the previous day, week, and month
- Manually adjust times as necessary to account for meetings and discussions
- Submit your adjusted times, on tasks you select, to your task repository
- Create reports in various formats

I'd recommend this [short video](http://www.tasktop.com/videos/1.2/introduction/reporting/) which explains the reporting features in about 6 minutes.

David Shepherd
[Tasktop Technologies](http://tasktop.com)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm actually aware of Tasktop Pro (nice product btw), but unfortunately it is a licensed product. Not that I would mind paying for a fine product (for work done on my own),  but it won't fly with the purchasing department. Plants would evolve and develop locomotion and the ability to feel pain before this gets traction, gets evaluated, approved and pulled out of the red tape tarpit unfortunately.

Comment: @luis: Triffids vs. bureaucracy?

Answer (score 1):

As you already know by now, the reporting functionality is included into commercial Tasktop product, which is developed by the same people who created Mylyn. So, obviously they are not interested to include some features into a free version. Now you have two options, either buy Tasktop, or develop your own extension for Mylyn. The task data is stored in reasonable simple xml file, so you not necessarily have to create an Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 1):

the reporting feature was stripped from the project when it used to be called mylar, in 2007, and since the project went commercial never came back to the open source mylyn for obvious reasons..
I found this simple perl script which outputs a pretty basic text only report, good enough for me.

http://rachaelandtom.info/mylyn-report

Answer (score 0):

No takers? Not surprised since I can't find anything on the subject. For what's worth, there is an experimental task/activity report available for Mylyn with the sandbox jar. However, I could not get mine to work as I'm tied up with a JBuilder installation behind a firewall (and I can't download anything on the corp network that is not pre-evaluated... it sucks, I know.)

I'm going to have to experiment with the mylyn sandox at home, but it would be great if someone knows of an easier, more stable alternative.